# How to listen to Fragment Change in Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

How can I add Fragment Change Listener in new Navigation Component?

I have a BottomNavigationView in which I used new Navigation Component following [official sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample)

I have four destinations in my `BottomNavigationView`, all of them have their navigation graphs.

```
val navGraphIds = listOf(R.navigation.nav_home, R.navigation.nav_discover, R.navigation.nav_search, R.navigation.nav_my)

val controller = bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(
    navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
    fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
    containerId = R.id.navHostContainer,
    intent = intent
)

controller.observe(this, Observer { navController ->
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
})
```

I want to have a listener in my `MainActivity` when fragment changed in any of 4 navigation graphs.

the `controller` is only affective when switching between `BottomNavigationView` destinations.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Have you tried `NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener`?

```
private lateinit var controller: NavController // don't forget to initialize

private val listener = NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
    // react on change
    // you can check destination.id or destination.label and act based on that
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    controller.addOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
}

override fun onPause() {
    controller.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
    super.onPause()
}
```

Comment: // don't forget to initialize --> Part will be 
`navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)` , where nav_host_fragment is fragment which contains `app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"`

Comment: Does it have to be added and removed? Why can't it just be added in onCreate and left there?

Comment: I have a question: shouldn't the listener also be removed in `onDestroy()`? Something like that: `override fun onDestroy() { controller.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(listener) super.onDestroy() }`

Answer (score 1):

Addition to marat and vlad answers , if u use FragmentContainer in Xml  , you can access it's nav controller by this :

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment 
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

else may encounter IllegalStateException of acitivity dont have navcontroller