# In Jetpack navigation, how to know which action trigger my fragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

With Jetpack navigation, I have Fragment A->B->C->B, For fragment B's onCreate, How to check B come from A or back from C.

Comment: onCreate won't be called when you go from C back to B

Comment: You can set a [navigation change listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284403/how-to-listen-to-fragment-change-in-navigation-component) and have it validated in `Activity`.

Comment: You can check the backstack

Comment: ADM answer is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass some data from framgent A->B or C->B.

As Example you can send integer value, or string or any other according to your requirement. I'm using integer for example

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/flow_step_one_dest"
android:name="com.example.android.codelabs.navigation.FlowStepFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/flow_step_one_fragment">
<argument
    android:name="flowStepNumber"
    app:argType="integer"
    android:defaultValue="1"/>

<action...>
</action>
```

and Fragment A and C you can pass value like this

```
val flowStepNumberArg = 1
val action = FragmentADirections.nextAction(flowStepNumberArg) //For Fragment A
//val action = FragmentCDirections.nextAction(flowStepNumberArg) //For Fragment C
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

and inside Fragment B you can retrieve by this:

```
val safeArgs: FlowStepFragmentArgs by navArgs()
val flowStepNumber = safeArgs.flowStepNumber
```

If you have not added dependencies for safeArgs than you can add it to project level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
//...
}
```

And in app level build.gradle at top add this line

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
```

If you need more understanding than check out [Google's Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html?index=..%2F..index#7)

Comment: I also wandering, if there are some code to check where the B come from. and don't update the navigation config file.

Comment: This is the proper way to pass some data to Fragment B. You just have to pass Int value like 1 from A and 2 for C fragments. And than check with safeArgs inside Fragment B. What is issue if you have just add simple arguments inside Frgamnet B navigation file?

Comment: No issue. Actually I use your method to track the source. but seems too much navigation need to change. my app related with a work flow process, different case have different work flow, but they actually the same UI page.

Comment: You do not need to change navigation, you just have to add arguments where you have used navigation only.There is other way to use ViewModel, if you know how to use ViewModel than you can use it.